# Does the debug banner automatically disappear on app bundle build from Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I've submitted my app for review on Google Play store. My understanding (and perhaps naivety) was that the Debug banner that appears in the top right hand corner would disappear automatically when creating an app build from Android Studio.

After uploading the app build (.aab file), and then downloading it through the Google Play store in Internal Test Mode, I've noticed the debug banner is still there. I didn't notice until now. This is the same app build that I have since sent for open release - which is currently pending Google's review.

In the screenshots though visible on the Google Play Console of how the app will look on various devices, I've noticed there is no debug banner.

Am I right to be concerned that my app will go live on the app store and have an ugly 'debug' banner plastered across the top right hand corner, or is this - by the power of magic fairies - going to disappear somehow before the app is released?

Or perhaps the powers at be in Google will notice the glaring error and reject the app from going live?

Answer (score 0):

This banner is only visible for **Debug** build. If you create a **Release** build then this banner would not be visible.

Also you can get rid of this banner forever:
https://medium.com/@apmntechdev/how-to-remove-debug-banner-in-flutter-5bb1727bbf5c

Comment: I have just rechecked my build.gradle file and it looks like a correct release build (signingConfig signingConfigs.release). I guess my confusion is why the internal download of the app, using the app build, still shows the debug banner - you would expect it to be removed from the Release app build (?

Comment: Can you tell me how you create release build? Yes this banner is not visible on release build

Comment: By using 'flutter build appbundle' on the command line after changing 'signingConfig signingConfigs.debug' to 'signingConfig signingConfigs.release' in build.gradle

Comment: I believe that you don't have to change this.

Please check https://flutteragency.com/make-release-apk-from-android-studio/ and 
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Comment: It was https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android I followed to the letter. if you check under Signing the App -> Configuring Signing in Gradle ..... it shows instructions for changing 'signingConfigs.debug' to 'signingConfigs.release' (?)

Comment: You added signing for builds, but did you created signed build?
For example this commnad `flutter build apk --release` should create release build

Comment: No, because I built with an App Bundle rather than APK. The instructions within that link does state by using 'Flutter Build' it defaults to a Release build (I guess rather than Debug)